# Paypal Adaptive Payment - how to automatically complete the process

Tags: javascript, paypal, paypal-adaptive-payments

~~I am using paypals adaptive payments API to make a sale from my site.

I have gotten it to work, to a point.

I have set up my api credentials. I have gotten it to the point where I can click a button on my site to initiate a payment, my site makes a call to the Paypal server and I get the PayKey returned. According to teh documentation I have read,. I insert the paykey into a form, and set a trigger on the forms submit button to start the lightbox process.

However, my customer has already initiated the process when s/he clicked the original button, so I want the form with the PayKey to submit automatically. The problem with this is I dont know how to set the light box trigger.

My Form that needs to be submitted is:

```
<form action="https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/webapps/adaptivepayment/flow/pay" target="PPDGFrame" name = "paypal_form"> 
                <input id="type" type="hidden" name="expType" value="light"> 
                <input id="paykey" type="hidden" name="paykey" value="RETURNED_PAYKEY_GOES_HERE">       
                <input type="submit" id="submitBtn" value="Pay with PayPal">    
        </form>
```

and I have a javascript trigger that starts the lightbox when the submit button is pressed:

```
var dgFlow = new PAYPAL.apps.DGFlow({ trigger: 'submitBtn' });
```

So if I press the button, the lightbox opens as required, however, I already initiated the sale when I pressed the button to get the PayKey, I dont want to have to press teh button again, and I have seen the lightbox process start on other sites without this second button click.

Answer (score 0):

You can use javascript to submit the form. To make it easier, give the form an id, here's an example that uses jQuery:

```
<form id="paypal-form" action="https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/webapps/adaptivepayment/flow/pay" target="PPDGFrame" name = "paypal_form"> 
    <input id="type" type="hidden" name="expType" value="light"> 
    <input id="paykey" type="hidden" name="paykey" value="RETURNED_PAYKEY_GOES_HERE">       
    <input type="submit" id="submitBtn" value="Pay with PayPal">    
</form>
<script>
    $('paypal-form').submit();
</script>
```